# CSV con carácter separador dentro de una columna

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Tengo un fichero csv que tiene como separador  una `,` pero existen algunas columnas de texto que tienen también `,` dentro de ellas. Por ejemplo la fila  `id` 12 tiene una `,` dentro del texto:

> movieId,title,genres
>   1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
>   2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
>   3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance
>   4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance
>   5,Father of the Bride Part II (1995),Comedy
>   6,Heat (1995),Action|Crime|Thriller
>   7,Sabrina (1995),Comedy|Romance
>   8,Tom and Huck (1995),Adventure|Children
>   9,Sudden Death (1995),Action
>   10,GoldenEye (1995),Action|Adventure|Thriller
>   11,"American President, The (1995)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
>   12,Dracula: Dead and Loving It (1995),Comedy|Horror

Comment: Y cual e tu pregunta?

Comment: Como dice Mark debes preguntar por el problema que se te plantea y además mostrar el código con el que intentas leer el "csv". Supongo que tu problema es el parseo del archivo, que como tal no es un csv en el momento que el separador está presente en el contenido.

Comment: Alfonso bienvenido al sitio, es importante como dicen los compañeros reformules tu pregunta en base a [ask]. Te invito también a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio.

Comment: Viendo tu ejemplo, las columnas con `,` en el contenido estas encerradas con dobles comillas si te sirve el dato: `"American President, The (1995)"`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tu observación no es nada trivial, de hecho esa es la clave para parsearlo siempre que todos los casos estén entrecomillados. Claro que depende de que esté usando para leer el csv porque NumPy está algo más limitado en este aspecto con respecto al módulo csv o Pandas.

Comment: @FJSevilla, lo que no recuerdo bien es si el módulo Csv, permite tratar de forma variable los entrecomillados, es decir celdas con comillas y celdas sin estas, que pareciera ser el caso.

Answer (score 1):

Como muy bién observó @PatricioMoracho las columnas que contiene el delimitador están acotadas por comillas dobles. NumPy está algo limitado en cuanto al parseo de archivos de texto y no soporta esta característica, pero si que lo hacen tanto el módulo `csv` de la biblioteca estándar de Python como Pandas. Pandas es posiblemente la mejor opción de las dos tanto para cargar como para trabajar con los datos, no obstante puedes obtener un array de NumPy a partir de ambas opciones si lo deseas.

- Usando el módulo csv:

  ```
  import csv


  with open("datos.csv") as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", quotechar ='"')
      header = next(reader)  # Eliminamos el header, quitar linea si lo queremos
      datos = list(reader)
  ```

  Si quieres un array de NumPy puedes usar la lista para construirlo mediante `np.array`, `np.asarray`, ...
- Usando Pandas:

  ```
  import pandas as pd

  df = pd.read_csv("datos.csv", delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
  ```

  Si quieres un array de Numpy puedes usar el atributo `df.values` o `df.as_matrix()`.

En ambos casos la clave está en usar adecuadamente el parámetro `quotechar`, por defecto son comillas dobles y que permite acotar fragmentos del archivo con caracteres especiales que no queremos que sean tratados como tales, como el propio delimitador, salto de línea, retorno de carro, etc.

Comment: Gracias por las repuestas, las próximas preguntas ya entiendo mejor como hacerlas y espero en poco tiempo ser de los que responden más que los que preguntan

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo que funciono perfecto fue el siguiente código

```
import pandas as pd
filem='./data_peliculas/ml-latest-small/movies.csv'
movies=pd.read_csv(filem,sep=",")
```